# Reading xml with XmlReader

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader

Here is xml that I want to read

```
<servers>
   <server name=" PIOU PIOU || OPTIMAL" ca="1" continent_code="EU" 
           country="France" country_code="FR" ip="s1.mymumble.fr" 
           port="20129" region="" url="http://www.mymumble.fr" />
</servers>
```

Now when I read it I successfully get the elemnt 'servers' and I can read its innerxml as well i.e the correct node is created. but when I create a node with element 'server' the node is empty.
I guess the reason is the short form of starting and ending element used in the 'server' node.
But my problem is that the xml comes from some remote server and I cannot modify it, so I have to read it the way it is written.

Here is my code to read XML:

```
List<XmlNode> nodeList = new List<XmlNode>();
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

while (reader.Read())
{
    //keep reading until we see my element
    if (reader.Name.Equals("server") && (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element))
    {
        XmlNode myNode = doc.ReadNode(reader);
        Debug.Log(reader.IsEmptyElement ? "its empty" : "not empty");
        //this always prints "its empty"        
        nodeList.Add(myNode);
    }        
}

foreach( XmlNode node in nodeList)
{
    Debug.Log("child:\t"+node.FirstChild.InnerXml);
}
```

Comment: "but when I create a node with element 'server'"... what does this mean?? Is there a reason you're using an XmlReader? Wouldn't it be easier to use LinqToXml?

Comment: as you can see the node server has a lot of info, like name, country etc. but nothing is there in that node which I create by 'doc.ReadNode(reader)'
No, there's no specific reason to use XmlReader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the documentation for [IsEmptyElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.isemptyelement.aspx). In particular, this example:

```
<item num="123"/> (IsEmptyElement is true).
<item num="123"></item> (IsEmptyElement is false, although element content is empty).
```

Your node is considered empty because it uses the short form. There is no element "content," but there *are* attributes.

Have you checked the node that you created (i.e. `myNode`) to see that it contains the attributes?

Comment: yeah Jim, thats what I was missing , should have looked, what emptyElement really means, Its quite confusing. Anyway thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

`XmlReader` is kind of low level for your needs...

Wouldn't it be easier to parse your XML with Linq2Xml?

```
var xmlStr = @"<servers>
   <server name="" PIOU PIOU || OPTIMAL"" ca=""1"" continent_code=""EU"" 
           country=""France"" country_code=""FR"" ip=""s1.mymumble.fr"" 
           port=""20129"" region="""" url=""http://www.mymumble.fr"" />
</servers>";


var doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlStr);
var servers = doc.Root.Elements("server")
                 .Select(e => new{
                    name = (string)e.Attribute("name"),
                    ca = (int)e.Attribute("ca"),
                    country = (string)e.Attribute("country")
                    //etc...
                 });
```

Answer (score 0):

XmlDocument has method called "GetNodes", that will help you.